# Softlayer API: filter image by OS referenceCode

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to filter out my `list of images by OS reference code`. Here is the url I am trying:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups.json?objectMask=mask[flexImageFlag]&objectFilter={'children': {'blockDevices': {'diskImage': {'softwareReferences': {'softwareDescription': {'referenceCode': {'operation': 'REDHAT_6_64'}}}}}}}
```

But I am kept getting the following error msg:

```
{"error":"Unable to parse object filter.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

Can anyone help me see what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Q.Z.

Answer (score 1):

The filter is wrong, but in my tests the filter is not working with the "referenceCode" property; you need to use another property such as name, version or both. See below the examples:

using name and version property

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectMask=mask[flexImageFlag]&objectFilter={"blockDeviceTemplateGroups": {"children":{"blockDevices":{"diskImage":{"softwareReferences":{"softwareDescription":{"name":{"operation":"CentOS"}, "version":{"operation":"6.3-32"}}}}}}}}
```

Using only a property (name in this case)

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectMask=mask[flexImageFlag]&objectFilter={"blockDeviceTemplateGroups": {"children":{"blockDevices":{"diskImage":{"softwareReferences":{"softwareDescription":{"name":{"operation":"CentOS"}}}}}}}}
```

Regards

Comment: Even though I don't understand why "referenceCode" can't be filtered on, your name filter works to certain degree. My goal is filtering out all the Windows 2008 images. By applying your suggestion, I have https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups.json?objectMask=mask[flexImageFlag,children[blockDevices.diskImage.softwareReferences.softwareDescription]]&objectFilter={"blockDeviceTemplateGroups": {"children":{"blockDevices":{"diskImage":{"softwareReferences":{"softwareDescription":{"name":{"operation":"!*= Windows 2008"}}}}}}}}. few images with 2008 returns

Comment: mmm, that seems an issue I suggest you to submit a ticket in softlayer for that. As a workaround you could try to add another property in your request such as {"longDescription":{"operation":"!*= Windows 2008"}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will submit a ticket to Softlayer. The issue is, not only few windows 2008 images couldn't be filtered out, some windows 2012 images are gone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the REST api. The example in the 
[API reference](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters), suggests that this parameter should be in JSON format:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,hostname]&objectFilter={"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}
```

Your error says "Unable to parse object filter.", so the error is probably just be that your parameter is invalid JSON: The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) only accepts  double quotes.

Try replacing

`{'children': {'blockDevices': {'diskImage': {'softwareReferences': {'softwareDescription': {'referenceCode': {'operation': 'REDHAT_6_64'}}}}}}}`

with the corresponding valid json:

`{"children": {"blockDevices": {"diskImage": {"softwareReferences": {"softwareDescription": {"referenceCode": {"operation": "REDHAT_6_64"}}}}}}}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I tried your example, it works, but looks like the filter doesn't do it work. I would expect it only returns all the instances in datacenter "dal05", but it returns all instances from all the datacenter.  https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests.json?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,datacenter]&objectFilter={"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}

Comment: try this filter: objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}}